# create template joomla3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

hi everyone I am using joomla 3 for my project

I create a template.  this is my templateDetail.xml

```
    <files>
        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>

    <positions>
        <position>menu</position>
        <position>cabecera</position>
        <position>slider</position>
        <position>carrusel</position>
        <position>noticias</position>
        <position>menuArquero</position>
        <position>menuHardware</position>
        <position>contenido1</position>
        <position>contenido2</position>
        <position>contenido3</position>
        <position>contenido4</position>
        <position>footer</position>
        <position>debug</position>

    </positions>

</extension>
```

I create my zip file and try to install but obtain this error

JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist /Users/maitepiedrayera/Sites/VistaMar/tmp/install_50eff5971c7cd/VistamarTemplate/js

any idea!

Comment: Try with adding an empty `index.html` file to the `js` directory.

Comment: No problem. Was just a guess... I think the ZIP either didn't contain the empty dir, or the empty dir was not extracted when installing the template...